# Raspberry Pi 3+ Windows 10 IoT: 24/7 running GPIO app

Tags: uwp, raspberry-pi, monitoring, gpio, windows-10-iot-core

I'm trying to create an Windows 10 C# UWP application for the Raspberry Pi 3+ that runs 24/7.

All that is done by the application is logging each interrupt of one of the GPIO pins into a file. The application itself is working fine, however i can't manage to get it running on the Pi 24/7 without getting suspended.

I already added the "extendedExecutionUnconstrained" capability to my UWP foreground app, tried converting my application to a background task app but nothing succeeded.

Are there any energy options on the Pi that need do be adjusted to achieve this?
Does anyone know how to run a application 24/7 on Windows 10 Iot?

Comment: Have you referred to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/run-in-the-background-indefinetly)? Hope it is helpful for you.

Comment: In addition, how did you check the application was suspended? Did the device hung up?

Comment: Hi, did you succeed in running app 24/7?. Please let me know.